# Understanding Binary Search bug

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, byte, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand **binary search** bug with `byte` array, I understood the concept of overflow that occurs while calculating the `mid` index. However when I simulate the same behaviour using `byte` array as follows:

```
public byte binarySearch(byte[] arr, byte low, byte high, byte value){

        if(low>high){
            return -1;
        }

        /* Line 1 */  byte overflow_mid = (byte) (((byte) (low + high))/2); // This line giving overflow behaviour

        /* Line 2 */  byte mid = (byte) ((low + high)/2);      // however this line doesn't, which is not what i expected

        if(arr[mid]== value){
            return mid;
        }

        if(arr[mid]>value){
            return binarySearch(arr, low, (byte) (mid-1), value);
        }
        return binarySearch(arr, mid, high, value);
    }
```

My intuition:

Since low and high variables are of type `byte`, I believe It doesn't need an explicit cast to `byte` again while calculating the **mid index** at line 2.

Thanks

Comment: Why use `byte` for `low` and `high`? They are index values, not values of the array, so just use `int` and you shouldn't have any overflow issues, plus it will eliminate the need for all those dang casts. Array index values are promoted to `int` anyway (see [JLS 15.13 Array Access Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)), so you're not really saving anything.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, but I am trying to understand the bug by simulating the integer behaviour using byte index and byte array, so i expect it to crash. Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that `byte low = 50, high = 100`.

The expression `low + high` will first promote both to `int`, then add them, resulting in value `150 (int)`.

In version 1, you then cast `150 (int)` to `byte`, which is value `-106 (byte)`. **Overflow**. Same as for `+`, the `/` operator will promote both sides to `int`, so it becomes `-106 (int)`, which is `-53 (int)` when divided by `2`. Finally you cast to `byte` again, ending up with `-53 (byte)`.

In version 2, you divide `150 (int)` by `2`, and since both sides are already `int` values, no promotion is done, ending up with `75 (int)`. Casting that to `byte` gives you `75 (byte)`. **No overflow**.

Comment: oh, that was my intuition too. didn't know that operators work with int only. damn, you Java. lol
Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You're casting two very different values.

In your first line, you're making two casts. The first one overflows. You're casting the result of `low + high` to byte, which overflows in your case.

However, in your second line you're casting `(low + high) / 2` to `byte`, and assuming both `low` and `high` are positive that means the result `r` has to be `low < r < high` and since both `low` and `high` can be represented by a `byte` variable, therefore so can the result `r` and there's no overflow.

Comment: but shouldn't the addition of two byte variables result into a byte, which would then overflow in this case.
i.e if low = 63 and high = 126 (both in byte)
then  low + high = -67

Comment: No, because `low + high` is evaluated as the sum of two *integers* which results as an `integer` itself, which is why you need the cast to `byte` in the first place.

Comment: yup, got it.
Thanks @Ori Lentz